# combining two sql queries into one?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two similar queries on same table and same where condition but different selects on it.

```
Select flatpos from archdetails
where version='1.3' AND compname IN (
    select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294'
)
```

AND

```
select count(distinct compname),
    sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    min(flatLoopIndex)
from archdetails
where version='1.3'
AND compname IN (
    select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294'
)
```

As you can see the query is on the same table `archdetails` and where condition is same for both as well.

query 1 will output something like

`12`
`47`

query 2 will output something like

`396 43 1`

I would like the output to be

`12 396 43 1`
`47 396 43 1`

I cannot obviously combine them by a group by.

Each one of these query runs in x amount of time. I know I can just put these queries into the from clause of a new query and get the desired result but then the new query runs in 2x amount of time.

Is there a faster way around since database essentially has to be scanned just once and then it is just a matter of formatting.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. Would do that immediately.

Comment: Formatting is not the job of your RDBMS. Those lines have nothing in common. Unless you do a CROSS JOIN (put the second query in the FROM clause of the first for MySQL), I don't see how you can do this.

Comment: Its not obvious to me, why can't you combine them by a group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the results of the first query into a temp table.

Then to get the first result set, `select *` from that temp table.

To get the second result set, join the temp table to the second query with no additional where clause statements and no columns selected from temp table.

(If the optimizer somehow manages to execute the second query N times, stash the results of second query into second temp table and join 2 temp tables)

```
create temporary table tmp1
Select flatpos from archdetails
where version='1.3' AND compname IN (
    select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294'
)

create temporary table tmp2
select count(distinct compname) as c,
    sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s,
    min(flatLoopIndex) as m
from archdetails
where version='1.3'
AND compname IN (
    select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294'
)

select * from tmp1

select tmp2.c, tmp2.s, tmp2.m from tmp1, tmp2
```

Comment: I reckon my original solution would be a lot faster  

`select t1.flatpos,t2.a,t2.b,t2.c  from (select flatpos from archdetails where version='1.3' AND compname IN (select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294')) as t1,(select count(distinct compname)as a,sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as b,min(flatLoopIndex) as c from archdetails where version='1.3' AND compname IN (select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294')) as t2`;

Comment: Not sure that's the case but to be honest too pressed for time to test - feel free to profile it to find out :)   Just make sure you test on large-ish data sets

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You might be able to gain some by removing one of the `'select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294''`

by

```
SELECT ad.flatpos , 
   totals.compname, 
   totals.inFlat, 
   totals.flatlooopindex

FROM
    archdetails ad
    INNER JOIN 
    (select count(distinct compname) compname,
        sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) inFlat,
        min(flatLoopIndex) flatlooopindex
    from archdetails
    where version='1.3'
     AND compname IN (
          select distinct compname from svn3 where revno='r270294'
    )) totals 
    ON ad.compname = totals.compname
```

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I mentioned in my question. This however takes 2x time. So no improvement. THanks though

Comment: Missed that last paragraph. I updated the answer to give an alternative

Comment: Not sure why but this returns an empty result. I think am going to stick to the original solution.